# Is Hindawi journal credible and valuable publication?

Tags: journals, computer-science, paper-submission

I have received several times an email from the **Hindawi** journal to invite me for submitting my article to this journal. However, I do not know this journal and I afraid if this journal a credible, trust-able and valuable publication? Or I have to ignore it?

Here is the link I received by email: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/scn/si/732327/cfp/

**Note:** My question is not that if an open access journal, in general, is valuable or not, but also there are some "Fraudulent" peer reviews publications (open access or not). I read an article on this journal from here: [Fraudulent peer review strikes another academic publisher; 32 articles questioned](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2015/07/08/fraudulent-peer-review-strikes-another-academic-publisher-32-articles-questioned/?utm_term=.66ab79a39a9d) which causes I aske this question.

Comment: I'll add that Hindawi's Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindawi_Publishing_Corporation) says a bit about the publisher. It was listed on Beall's list at some point, but not when Beall's list was taken down.

Comment: Have you looked at the publications produced by that journal? Would you want to be listed with them? Can you afford it? These are all relevant questions that you should answer.

Comment: If you get a mail asking you to publish and you don't know the sender then it's always a scam

Comment: I'll suggest a related heuristic to the one that our friends at Finance.SE use to assess whether a "financial opportunity" is a scam - **if you even have to ask the question, it's scam.** Don't publish there.

Comment: I don't know about this particular journal. However, Advances in High Energy Physics [https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ahep/] is a respectable journal in the high energy physics(although not on top). You can check the editorial board here [https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ahep/editors/] where you can see that most of the editors publish in high impact journals and are very credible scientists.

Comment: @NikeyMike I was searching for this question as I am considering submitting to AHEP. I want to add that this particular journal is included in SCOAP3, so no way it is bad.